# On a LAMP stack, how to limit the number of concurrent connections and serve a static page for those who are beyond that limit?

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I'm aware of the Apache directives `MaxClients` and `ListenBacklog`. I'm trying to set a limit of, let's say 100 concurrent connections after which the new connections will be served a static page.
Can this be done? Should MaxClients and ListenBacklog be higher or lower than that limit? How can I test it?

Comment: Good question, you might have better luck on serverfault.com though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it:
Let's say that I want to allow X concurrent requests, after which the following Y concurrent requests will stay in a queue, waiting for the first X to finish, and everything exceeding X+Y will be served a static page:

1. In `httpd.conf` the following directives must be set:

   ```
   MaxClients X
   ServerLimit X
   ListenBacklog Y
   ```
2. Logged as root in MySQL, set `max_connections`:

   ```
   set global max_connections = X
   ```
3. Edit the `.htaccess` file from your server's public root folder:

   ```
   ErrorDocument 503 error_503.html
   ```
4. Make sure that your error_503.html is served in one request. All stylesheets and scripts must be in this file. If you want to include images, you'll have to use the [data uri scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). Also, you'll have to slice your images up because in IE data URIs have to be smaller than 32KiB.

Answer (score 1):

If you can place nginx in the front of apache, you can try this nginx module https://github.com/cfsego/nginx-limit-upstream . It limits number of connections to apache and place other connections to queue. It's not exactly what you are looking for, but, I think, it's possible to modify module to render a static page instead of placing to queue.